# データの結合と合算

Tags: python, pandas

2つのデータを結合して、重複するデータがあれば合算したい。

```
# データ1
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"送信元IP": [1.1.1.1, 3.3.3.3, 5.5.5.5], 
                    "宛先IP": [2.2.2.2, 4.4.4.4, 6.6.6.6], 
                    "宛先ポート": [53, 55, 22],
                    "合計":[1,1,1]})
# データ2
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"送信元IP": [1.1.1.1, 3.3.3.3, 5.5.5.5], 
                    "宛先IP": [2.2.2.2, 4.4.4.4, 6.6.6.6], 
                    "宛先ポート": [53, 55, 22],
                    "合計":[1,1,1]})
```

#### これまでに試したこと

Concatを使ってdf1とdf2を結合した後、以下のコードで合計欄を結合後の値になるようにしました。

```
df3=pd.concat(["df1","df2",ignore_index=True)
dfx = df3.groupby(df.columns.tolist(), as_index=False).size().rename({'size': '合計'}, axis=1)
print(dfx)
```

理想としては、2つのデータを結合した際に重複する値に関しては、合計欄が合算した値になるようにしたいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "送信元IP": ['1.1.1.1', '3.3.3.3', '5.5.5.5'],
    "宛先IP": ['2.2.2.2', '4.4.4.4', '6.6.6.6'],
    "宛先ポート": [53, 55, 22],
    "合計":[1,1,1]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "送信元IP": ['1.1.1.1', '3.3.3.3', '5.5.5.5'],
    "宛先IP": ['2.2.2.2', '4.4.4.4', '6.6.6.6'],
    "宛先ポート": [53, 55, 22],
    "合計":[1,1,1]})

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
dfx = df3.groupby(df3.columns.tolist(), as_index=False).size()\
         .drop('合計', axis=1).rename({'size': '合計'}, axis=1)
print(dfx)
```

| 送信元IP | 宛先IP | 宛先ポート | 合計 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1.1.1 | 2.2.2.2 | 53 | 2 |
| 3.3.3.3 | 4.4.4.4 | 55 | 2 |
| 5.5.5.5 | 6.6.6.6 | 22 | 2 |

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ファイル結合の段階で重複するデータについては合計欄のみを増やすといったことはできないでしょうか。

Comment: 合計欄が最後の列にある、という前提であれば `dfx = df3.groupby(df3.columns.tolist()[:-1], as_index=False).size().rename({'size': '合計'}, axis=1)` でしょうか。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。例えば、データフレームのうちの1合計が１ではなく、50だとしても、ご教示頂いたコードでは合計は3としてカウントしてしまいます。

Comment: はい、その場合は `dfx = df3.groupby(df3.columns.tolist()[:-1], as_index=False).agg({'合計': 'sum'})` になるかと。

Comment: ありがとうございます。勉強になりました。

Comment: すみません。やはり、正しく集計されませんでした。各日の集計データは正しく取れていますが、マージしたデータでは、既に日毎の集計が5000以上あるにも関わらず、それ以下の集計数が結果として反映されています。